# Getting error "A problem occurred while processing the request" while integrating ZAP with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, owasp, zap

I am trying to integrate ZAP with Jenkins and following https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/owasp-zap-integration-jenkins-devsecops-pipeline-basic-arpit-mittal

I am using Mac machine and Jenkins is installed in my local. I did all the settings given in the above doc.
Still I am getting error

Steps Performed:

Install "Official OWASP ZAP Jenkins Plugin" by navigating to "Plugin Manager"
[image]

Provide OWASP ZAP path in "Custom Tool" by navigating to "Global tool Configuration" from where ZAP will be install.
[image]

Navigate to "Configuration" to set the Host, Port and Environment Variables for ZAP.
[image]

[image]

Create Freestyle Project named ZAP

In "Build Environment" check on the "Install Custom Tools" for ZAP and when you click on "Tool Selection" you'll get the ZAP details which we have submitted at the time of configuration.
[image]

Navigate to the "Build" process like the path of ZAP, host and port details. You can change it as per your requirement.
[image]

Now set the "Installation Method" to "System Installed" where ZAP will be installed. Provide environment variable and set the "ZAP Home Directory"
[image]

[image]

Now we will provide the scan details of the web application on which we want to perform vulnerability assessment. Navigate to "Session Management" and select "Persistent Session."
[image]

[image]

Configure the report part to generate an automated report and publish HTML report for the scan.
[image]

After doing all this configuration when I click on Apply, I get
[image]

Please help me here.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The "Official OWASP ZAP Jenkins Plugin" actually isnt supported by the ZAP core team any more and is not recommended.

The recommended ways to automate ZAP are explained on https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/

Comment: Thanks Simon. Will try to use the above methods to automate ZAP